# How to use sqlite database with Osmdroid?

Tags: osmdroid

While it is said that sqlite database is recommended format for offline map tiles (https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles) there is no really example how to use it. I have my sqlite file generated with mobac app but how to load it?

Any example would be helpful!

My environment is Xamarin, VS, Android.

Answer (score 3):

Well I can't speak for Xamarin, but to use sqlite databases with osmdroid, simply get the file on device at /sdcard/osmdroid/yourfile.sqlite

then start osmdroid or whatever app it's running in

Then you need to tell osmdroid to display whatever tile source is in the sqlite's 'provider' column. This is documented at the following links

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources#using-a-different-tile-source

I agree, the wiki could use some clarification on this. In short, osmdroid runs a routine to discover all tile sources available offline when it starts up (with the default tile provider). Then when you switch tile sources, it will attempt to fulfill the tile request with all available sources until trying online source.

To summarize,

1. prepare your sqlite file
2. transfer to device /sdcard/osmdroid/
3. tell osmdroid to use a tile source that matches the 'provider' column in the database (and optionally set offline mode mapview.setUseDataConnection(false))
4. start it up

Comment: Thanks for your work on OSMDroid! I'm having trouble using offline maps.. I use the SqliteArchiveTileWriter and the CacheManager to download data into /sdcard/osmdroid/mydata.sqlite and I set the default provider to Mapnik. (This is only an internal demo app, no-one will ever use it in public)
Is there anything I need to do in order to load those tiles? Any file provider to set?

Comment: you might just have to reset the map view's tile provider. Something like mapView.setTileProvider(new MapTileProviderBasic(...)). This should force the discovery part to happen again

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately this does not help. Map tiles are even not loaded on app restart. I thought that I might load the data into the wrong location, since I can’t find the cache.db of OSMdroid in that directory

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Thank you very much! Turns out, the correct path was /data/data/$app-identifier/osmdroid. Inside that folder I found the cache.db. I am using the simulator, maybe that was the reason..

Comment: That was implemented because no one reads androids docs on runtime user permissions.  If permissions are not granted, the map reverts to app private storage